# No se encuentra en la vista la ruta de las imágenes en el MVC con PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un problema en la vista utilizando el patron MVC estoy cargando una imagen y no la carga porque no reconoce la ruta.

Tengo un archivo controladores.php que estan las funciones referentes a la vista.

```
function vistaHome(){
require "templates/principal.php";}
```

La vista principal.php

```
<nav id="nav">
<div id="logo-nav">
  <img src="logo.png" alt="Logotipo">
</div>

<ul>
  <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Servicios</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Trabajos</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
```

Y el controlador frontal que es el index.php

```
require_once "modelo.php";
require_once "controladores.php";
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_PATH);
$urlDividida=explode('/',$url);
$finalUrl= $urlDividida[count($urlDividida)-1];
switch ($finalUrl) {
    case 'index.php':
        vistaHome();
        break;
    case 'servicios':       
            vistaServicios();        
        break;
    case 'trabajos':
        vistaGaleria();
        break;
    
    case 'contacto':
        vistaContactame();
    break;
    
    default:
        echo "La pagina no existe";
        die();
        break;
}
```

El archivo logo.png esta al mismo nivel que el archivo principal.php y no me carga la imagen.

Si accedo directamente al archivo principal.php sin pasar por el index.php si me la carga.
No entiendo porque no me deja cargarla al pasar por el index.php ya que el index es el que se encarga de cargar una vista u otra dependiendo de la url

¿Alguien sabe porque sucede esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No te carga porque sino me equivoco tu estructura es la siguiente:

```
index.php
templates/principal.php
templates/logo.png
```

Sin embargo, cuando ejecutas el index.php estás llamando a la imagen así:

```
<img src="logo.png" alt="Logotipo">
```

Fíjate que la ruta desde `index.php` hacia el directorio de logo.png es **templates/** por lo tanto la forma correcta **relativa** de llamarlo desde el `index.php` es:

```
<img src="templates/logo.png" alt="Logotipo">
```

Da igual como invoques a los archivos php internamente. Lo importante es lo que ellos **generan como salida *html***, la cual debe **respetar el lugar desde donde son invocados**, en este caso `index.php` desde la raíz de tu web.

Cuando accedes a `principal.php` ves la imagen porque realmente, si te fijas en la *ruta del url del navegador*, estás en `templates/principal.php`, por lo tanto **ya estás en `templates/`** y por eso el logo.png no necesita la ruta para mostrarse.

Otra solución pasaría por **poner toda la ruta absoluta desde la raíz de tu sitio web**, en ese caso se vería siempre en cualquier circunstáncia porque evitarías **rutas relativas**, como las explicadas hasta ahora. Por ejemplo así:

```
<img src="http://misitio.com/templates/logo.png" alt="Logotipo">
```

En este caso te funcionaría desde el `index.php`, desde el `templates/principal.php` y desde cualquier lugar (incluido otras webs con ese atributo `src=` en el elemento `img`, a menos que tengas las imágenes protegidas).

Otro tema a tener en cuenta es porqué llamas principal.**php** a un archivo que tan solo contiene **html** sin ningún código php. Quizás podrías renombrarlo a principal.**html** si no tienes intención de usar php con el.